# MKMapView not updating user position image

Tags: iphone, ios, location, mkmapview

My MKMapView shows my position at startup but then the image never 'follows' me. The location gets updated and the screen does follow me, but the original "User Location" image stays behind.

Here is some code snippets:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    if(!pinView)
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];

        if(annotation == mapView.userLocation) customPinView.image = [self rotate:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myCar.png"] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        else customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"randomPin.png"];

        customPinView.animatesDrop = NO;
        customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        return customPinView;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}

-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [location coordinate];
    if(isFollowing)
        [myMapView setCenterCoordinate:loc];//Works
}
```

and in my `viewDidLoad` I do call: `[myMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];` which does work.

So basically somewhere I neglect updating my position or its most possibly where I draw the new image for my current position.

Can anyone possibly see what I am missing or doing wrong there for it to not follow my location updates?

Thanks.

Comment: did you solve the problem ? I haver exactly the same one.

Comment: Sorry, cant remember - happened too long back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear if this is the issue but the viewForAnnotation method doesn't look right.

The annotation image is only being set when an annotation view is created.  If a view is re-used, the annotation property is updated but not the image.  It's possible that the re-used view is for an annotation of a different type requiring a different image.

The method should look something like this:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];               
        pinView.animatesDrop = NO;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) 
        pinView.image = [self rotate:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myCar.png"] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    else 
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"randomPin.png"];

    return pinView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like It will work now. Your solution is what I suspected I should do but did not know how. Will mark correct after test.

Comment: @Anna, this solution does not solve the problem. The image still gets drew and the view follows the position, but the image remains on its original place.

Comment: Does locationUpdate get called from CLLocationManager's didUpdateToLocation delegate method?  Do you also have any code in the map view's didUpdateUserLocation delegate method?  Can you check whether the CLLocationManager's current location coordinates match the map view's userLocation?  Also, if you tap on the userLocation annotation on the map (the one that doesn't move), does it say "Current Location"?  Another thing to check: At the top of viewForAnnotation, check if annotation is of type MKUserLocation and return nil in that case and see if the blue dot follows you.

Comment: `locationUpdate` does get called from there. I don't have a `didUpdateUserLocation`. If I tap on that, it does show "Current Location". Note: the mapview follows me (my pos stay center of screen) but not the icon/image/indicator. That last line, must I change it back to rather show the blue dot and test the dot following me? Hope you can help me further! thank you!

Comment: The last suggestion can help confirm that the map view's userLocation has the same coordinates as the ones you are using to center the map.  Another option is to implement didUpdateUserLocation and compare the coordinates to the ones you are using to center the map.  Still another test is to completely disable the viewForAnnotation method and just do the centering.  This should give you a blue dot with red pins for your own annotations.

Comment: Your basic approach should be working and I don't see any obvious problem in the code shown.  Finally, since you are using your own image for the current location anyway, you could always set showsUserLocation to NO and manually add and move your own annotation for the current location (it would have to use a class that implements setCoordinate so you can update the coordinates in locationUpdate).

Comment: I am thinking of changing back to the blue dot, the `course` outputted by CLLocation is to jumpy/unreliable to be responsible for turning (yet to be implemented) the image of the car... so thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I just noticed although probably not the cause of the original problem, but: You need to use MKAnnotationView instead of MKPinAnnotationView since you are using your own image.  Will also not need "animatesDrop = NO".

Comment: I've had the exact same problem. It seems the MKUserLocation is not updated for some strange reason. The best alternative is to indeed not show anything and create your own Annotation and AnnotationView.

Comment: @alper, Yes I was also able to reproduce the problem with MKUserLocation but couldn't understand why.  I think only choice is to use CLLocationManager instead to get the user location and create your own annotation as you said.